# Differences among the sentences starting with 'it is better' , 'it will be better' or it would have been better

Tags: usage

In my office I wrote an application, part of which reads

> 'it is better if you take a look at my loan papers'

This happened twice. are the sentences incorrect? I could have written

> 'It will be better/it would be better
>
> 'if you take a look at my loan papers'

which of the three sentences are correct and appropriate? or I could have written

> 'it would have been better if you had taken  a look at my loan papers"

But There was no uproar.

I think there is no need to change the original sentence-'It is better if you take a look at my loan papers" THE TELEGRAPH daily English news paper of KOLKATA, INDIA published two articles not very long ago which endorses my view.                 If we use colloquial English in construction of sentences, it is  down voted because ,  in such sentences  inappropriate tags[1]Grammar [2]Grammatically ,  were used,  but not down voted in tags like [1]Usage 
I request you reconsider my this very question, which is edited.Many non- native speakers translate their own language into English,  if they have to speak or  write hastily.

Comment: Hi. "It is/will be better if" are [hardly ever used in English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+will+be+better+if%2Cit+would+be+better+if%2C+it+is+better+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - probably because they could be perceived as too direct and somewhat rude.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. It is better if you take a look at my loan papers.
> 2. It will be better if you take a look at my loan papers.
> 3. It would be better if you take a look at my loan papers.
> 4. If you take a look at my loan papers *[needs a verb and predicate]*

Sentence 1 would work perfectly fine. You're saying that looking at the papers is better than not looking at them.

Sentence 2 is is grammatically okay but doesn't work as well. I think the reason is that "will be better" implies a situation that can be improved, not one that is superior to another.

If you say "It will be better in the morning" you're talking about one thing improving, and comparing itself at different points in time, not comparing that one thing to a different thing that exists at the same time.

In sentence 3, you're using the [subjunctive mood](https://grammarist.com/grammar/subjunctive-mood/) with *would be*. This is the best option because the subjunctive mood is used to express a suggestion.

Sentence 4 is incomplete. It needs a verb/predicate, but once it has one, it could be just as usable as Sentence 3. For example:

> If you take a look at my loan papers, **you will better see what I am talking about**.